# Perl - Reading file lines

Tags: perl, file, foreach, line

I'm trying to read the lines on a file with the code below. But the result of this code is to print the same line as lines the document has.

```
open (file_to_rand, "./files/file07.txt") or die "Could not open file";
foreach $line (<file_to_rand>) {
    push(@array,$line);
}
close(file_to_rand);
```

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: No, the "result" of this code is not to print anything. The only thing in this code that can possibly output anything is `die`. Also, the sentence `"to print the same line as lines the document has"` is a syntax error and doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to **read all lines into array** (this is not effective for big files):

```
open my $fh, "<",  "./files/file07.txt" or die "Could not open file";
my @lines = readline($fh);
close $fh;
#possible you need to remove new line character at the end of each line:
chomp @lines;
```

By the way: it's Perl and **not PERL**

Comment: Unless this PERL people keep talking about is a completely different animal that regular guys like us never heard about.